# Principal Component Analysis to select feature?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If I have a 3x3 covariance matrix that has 3 eigenvector/value pairs as disovered when I did PCA, how do I actually know which columns in my original data matrix (like the one I used to calculate the covariance matrix) eigenvector/value pair belongs to?

So, PCA lets you select which feature/column(in my case) that is most important. This is evaluated by variance (eigenvalue). Thus, there most be some connection between a certain eigenvalue and a certain column/feature. So I want to know how I can find this connection to select the most important feature.

Comment: The answer is the same as the last time you asked it: eigenvectors are not generally basis vectors, so are not associated to a single column, but a linear combination of columns.

Comment: Nono, I added the last part after which I thought it was a little different.

Comment: I am not necessarily talking about the eigenvectors. More the eigenvalues which must be associated with some component/column because otherwise, how would you use it to select the most important features?

Comment: The vectors associated to the eigenvalues are the eigenvectors. As these are not generally basis vectors, they are not generally associated to single columns, but to linear combinations of them.

Comment: @user3482749 Hmm then I must have misunderstood something when my professor taught it. How do you then use PCA to rank features based on their importance?

Comment: The way that I learnt it was that the eigenvalues represents variance of the different components and from that you could rank the features.

Comment: @user3482749 it will be the final question. Please help me out - getting desperate :(

Comment: You've misunderstood the word "feature". It's not the same as "column". That's really it.

Comment: Thank you. Your last comment probably helped more than you think